# Conditional Formatting if one time is greater than the other

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm attempting to get excel to conditionally format a cell based on if it is 5 minutes greater than the value in the column next to it.  It's to compare times to see if a person was late to work, we accept a 5 minute variance.  If they are late, I want to format that cell showing the clock in time with pink fill and red bold letters.  Below is a picture of the two columns though they are jumbled a bit.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlrgR.jpg] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula in the conditional formatting for Actual Arrival Time column cells

**=IF(HOUR(C3)=HOUR(B3),IF(MINUTE(C3)-MINUTE(B3)>5,TRUE,FALSE),IF(HOUR(C3)>HOUR(B3),TRUE,FALSE))**

where column C has actual times and column B schedules times

To set this up go to HOME > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" > enter the formula provide above and use the "Format" button to specify the highlighting that you'd like

Per further specifications noted below, use the following formula as an ADDITIONAL CONDITIONAL RULE to highlight (specify a different format) arrivals more than 5 mins early

**=IF(HOUR(C3)=HOUR(B3),IF(MINUTE(B3)-MINUTE(C3)>5,TRUE,FALSE),IF(HOUR(C3)-HOUR(B3)=-1,IF(MINUTE(C3)-60,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE))**

Comment: Thank you Petr Fedorov !  It works almost perfect.  But I left something out. I'd also like the formatting to take place if the person clocked in more than 5 mins b4 their time.  This formula covers that but it highlights all "negative time"  Would there be a way to limit that formatting to only times >5 minutes before the scheduled time?  Thanks so much for your help. Here's a link to what I got when I used the formula as is.  Also for whatever reason, it seems to also effect some that are < 5 min greater than the scheduled time.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/u353uywmavzh00o/Clipboard01.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Nic, I edited the original answer to handle your original specifications.
Would you like to have different formatting for early arrivals (5 mins early)?

Comment: That would be awesome, for arrivals that are >5 minutes early.   Perhaps from the comparison of those two can help me learn how to adapt it to my other formatting needs as well.  Thanks again for your help @petr

Comment: Nic, I edited the original post again: add another rule with the provided formula.

Comment: Nic, is everything performing as you wished?

Comment: Hello.  Thanks for asking.  Actually, it the formatting doesnt seem to capture all the times actual arrival times that are greater than  5 minutes than the schedule time.  Not sure if this makes any difference but the table I am formatting is a pivot table that is automatically feeding data from other sheets that are updated daily.

Comment: Let's try simplifying reply the formula for the late formatting with =IF(C1-B1>0.0034837962962963,TRUE,FALSE)...and replace the formula for the early arrivals with =IF(C1-B1<-0.0034837962962963,TRUE,FALSE). If these work better then I'll edit my answer. Apologies then I didn't get this right.